# Illuminated cloud create scratch org from file

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org, illuminatedcloud

How I can use `scratch-def.json` for creating new org without using DX CLI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to "Manage Connections" from the IC toolbar (it's a on the drop-down that says "Open Connection"). Click on the DX Icon in the top-left to start creating a scratch org.

On the new scratch org dialog, there's a folder icon next to the field for Org Name. You can use that to pick an existing `scratch-def.json`. The the dialog will be populated with the setting from that file.

This is particularly useful when your scratch org has expired on an existing project.

[image]

Comment: That's good feedback. If the discoverability of that feature is low, I can change it to something more obvious, perhaps a hyperlink like **Load scratch org definition**. I'm certainly open to feedback on how it could be improved.